# Modifying the data in a collection directly?

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way in Python3 to modify the data in a collection directly?

For example, the below code:

```
var1, var2 = 0, 0
for data in [var1, var2]:
  data += 1
```

Outputting:

```
> var1
>>> 1
> var2
>>> 1
```

Is there any way to achieve what I am attempting to do above?

Comment: No, when you write `[var1, var2]` this creates a list with _copies_ of the two integers.

Comment: It's best to share some input data - to make your interest clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with ints, because they are immutable (https://realpython.com/pointers-in-python/#immutable-vs-mutable-objects); it can work with mutable objects however.
E.g. you could wrap your values in a list:

```
var1, var2 = [0], [0]
for i in [var1, var2]:
    i[0] += 1
print(var1[0]) # 1
print(var2[0]) # 1
```

You could also implement your own mutable int class for this instead of using lists.

**But** just because you can, doesn't necessarily mean that you should. There's probably a simpler way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can use function for this goal :)

```
var1 ,var2= 0,0
def add(var1,var2,data):
    data  = 0
    while data < 2:
        var1 = var1+ data
        var2 = var2 + data
        data += 1
    return var1,var2
    

print(add( 0 ,0,1))
```